# Remove identical records in mySQL

Tags: mysql, duplicates, records

I have columns **ID**, **A**, and **B**. in Table1

ID = Autonumber, Primary key

A = Foreign key

B = Foreign key

This table is for many to many and let's ignore column ID for now.
I need to remove duplicates from my many to many.

example:

```
+----+---+
| A  | B |
+----+---+
| 1  | 1 |
| 1  | 2 |
| 1  | 1 |
| 1  | 2 |
| 1  | 3 |
| 2  | 1 |
+----+---+
```

Turn it into

```
+----+---+
| A  | B |
+----+---+
| 1  | 1 |
| 1  | 2 |
| 1  | 3 |
| 2  | 1 |
+----+---+
```

removing those unnecessary duplicates. 
can you help me with the query for MySQL, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a table of any size, it is often faster to truncate the table and re-insert records then to do a massive delete.  This is particularly true when the table in question has no primary key.

Hence, I would recommend something like this:

```
create table temp_table1 as
    select distinct a, b
    from table1;

truncate table table1;

insert into table1(a, b)
    select a, b
    from table1;
```

Of course, make a copy of `table1` before doing anything -- just in case.